# Is there any way to make a file instance persist for all users in a website

Tags: web, heroku, webserver

I have a file which is around 1.2 GB size and I want to call an instance to it while formulating results for my website. Is it possible to make the instance the same for all users of the website? According to my understanding,  for eg Heroku, as all create separate instances of the website for every user, is there any way to make it happen. I apologize in advance if the question is naive !!

Comment: You'll need to use a service to host the file, like Amazon S3.

Comment: So will Amazon load the file instance for every user or will it persist?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but Amazon S3 is for hosting static files.

Comment: I need to use the object of this file for various calculations and I am not sure loading 1 GB file for every user is practical in terms of speed and storing in amazon s3 - is it a better way to load an instance from Amazon or is there any way to store instance to the object permanently in Heroku . Is this more clear?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I was under the impression that you just wanted to serve the file to users.

Comment: "According to my understanding, for eg Heroku, as all create separate instances of the website for every user"—this is incorrect. But you won't be able to include a 1.2 gigabyte file in your slug anyway. The [maximum slug size](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#slug-size), which must include your application, runtime, and data, is currently 500 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Bummer, heroku only allows you to have 500mb of files in your deploys.

If not for that, you could just commit that big file to your repo and use it on your site.

Heroku doesn't create an instance of the app for every user but for every deploy. Once you deploy your application, your entire old server is thrown away and a new one is created.

Let's say you need a temporary file, you could put it on /tmp/something and then use it for a while. Once you make a deploy, as the server is discarded and a new one is spawn, that file wouldn't be there and you'd have to recreate it for the first request.

Anyway, that doesn't look good. Even if heroku would let you store the file there, you'd also have to parse and dig through it in order to display your results for your site, which is likely to make you run out of memory too.

I would recommend you to review your approach to this problem, maybe break that file in small pieces or store it in a database to perform smaller calculations.

If there is absolutely no way around it, you could have a server in some other server like digital ocean and build a small api to perform the calculations there and make your site call it.

If you want, I can give you a hand on switching the approach for it, just post a different question, comment the link to it and I'll give it a shot.